# Где увидеть различие в версиях qt?

Tags: qt

Я знаю, есть большая таблица, которая показывает что добавлено добавилось, удалилось, переместилось, от версии к версии. Найти не как не могу

Answer (score 1):

Вот [здесь](https://wiki.qt.io/Main) в таблице `Quick Access` есть ссылки на списки того, что добавили в новой версии.

Comment: Может не на официальном сайте, но я точно видел большую таблицу(все версии qt по порядку и рядом изменения).